# whats wrong with this code??(c1.CommandText = "insert into stu values='" + textBox1 + "','" + textBox2 + "'";)

Tags: c#, sql-server

Hi i write a simple code in C# for insert some name on a SQLDatabase

this is my Full Code

i have this error

***Unable to connect on server***

---

```
namespace CsharpProject
{
    public partial class From2 : Form
    {
        public From2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string s1 = "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=test1;Integrated Security=True";
            SqlConnection sc1 = new SqlConnection(s1);
            SqlCommand c1 = new SqlCommand("",sc1);
            c1.CommandText = "insert into stu values='" + textBox1 + "','" + textBox2 + "'";
            try
            {
                sc1.Open();
                if (c1.ExecuteNonQuery() == 1)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("successes");
                    textBox1.Focus();

                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Error ");
                    textBox2.Focus();
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Unable to connect on server ");
                textBox2.Focus();
            }
            finally{
            sc1.Close();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

**and i think my problem is Here But I cant solve it**

```
c1.CommandText = "insert into stu values='" + textBox1 + "','" + textBox2 + "'";
```

Please Help Me 
Thanks

Comment: query syntax is wrong here is right synatx:``insert into stu values(val,val2)``

Comment: `Unable to connect to server` - I'm sorry but there is no way that relates to building your SQL query. Think about what the error is saying. `Connect`... mmm.. perhaps `Connection`...

Comment: connection string is also wrong which is reason of that exception

Comment: @HenkHolterman Ah yes.. fair enough. Guess I should have read the code.

Comment: i use catch (ex) and show TEXT:insert

Comment: You must check your SQL Server connection string.

Comment: There Is many things wrong with your code, one of them is probably textBox1.Text in your command text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should be..

```
c1.CommandText = "insert into stu values('" + textBox1.Text + "','" + textBox2.Text + "')";
```

but I'd suggest you to use parameterized SQL query to avoid SQL injection attacks

here is how your query will look after parameterising

```
c1.CommandText = "insert into stu values(@textBox1, @textBox2)";

c1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@textBox1", textBox1.Text)
c1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@textBox2", textBox2.Text)
```

here is an useful link that will help you to know more about parameterized queries.

## **Using Parameterized queries to prevent SQL Injection Attacks in SQL Server**

Answer (score -1):

if you have more than one sql instance you should add instance name after .\ in source attribute of connection string.

If you are sure about conectionString try this:

```
c1.CommandText = string.Format("insert into stu (col1, col2) values ({0}, {1})", textBox1, textBox2);
```

Answer (score -1):

You're missing a close bracket

```
c1.CommandText = "insert into stu values('" + textBox1 + "','" + textBox2 + "')";
```

Answer (score -1):

What's really wrong is that you're not parameterising your SQL query.  (ie: http://buddylindsey.com/sql-parameters-in-c/)  This leaves you open to SQL injection attacks - see http://bobby-tables.com/